# Быстрая смена сетевых настроек. python

Tags: python, ip

Хочу написать програмульку для смены сетевых настроек на PC. я только начал изучать Python потому хотелось бы написать ее в Python. Подскажие какие библиотеки использовать. Я жумал с помощью socket сделать...но так можно только прочесть некоторые настройки... а вот как их изменить пока не понимаю. Подкиньте идею)

Comment: http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/49/49/lecture/27074

Comment: смена ip mask, dns

Comment: Для виндовс - реестр и винапи. Для линукс - дбас на нетворкменеджер.

Comment: так что за система - винда, или линукс?

Comment: для виндовс десять

Comment: Проще, наверное, через командную строку, команды netsh и route. Даже питон не обязателен, если просто поменять настройки, без какой-то логики выбора.

Comment: согласен на счёт командной строки. но нужно сеть програмку)) что бы одной кнопкой менялись настройки)) на робочий компьютер)) там не все умеют командной строкой)